# Iterating through a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, homework

I am trying to get my dictionary to iterate seven times after the `dateTime` is found. I want to iterate through the next week of objects in my dictionary `pagesInRange`. I figured out how to do it, but I am sure this is not good code. I am wondering if someone could point me in the direction of what I can do to improve this code.

I could not figure out how to iterate through the range I want, so instead I iterate through the entire dictionary and have a bunch of it statements to find the values I am looking for. Here is my code. I know I can use a `switch` statement to improve the code, but I wondering if there is a way given the first value to iterate over the next seven values.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a date in the following formate MM/DD/YYYY");
string date = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
DateTime end1 = dt.AddDays(1);
DateTime end2 = dt.AddDays(2);
DateTime end3 = dt.AddDays(3);
DateTime end4 = dt.AddDays(4);
DateTime end5 = dt.AddDays(5);
DateTime end6 = dt.AddDays(6);

int i = 0;
foreach (var pair in pagesInRange)
{
    if (pair.Key.ToString("d")==date)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString("d") + " " + pair.Value);
    } else if (pair.Key == end1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString("d") + " " + pair.Value);
    }
    else if (pair.Key == end2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString("d") + " " + pair.Value);
    }
    else if (pair.Key == end3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString("d") + " " + pair.Value);
    }
    else if (pair.Key == end4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString("d") + " " + pair.Value);
    }
    else if (pair.Key == end5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString("d") + " " + pair.Value);
    }
    else if (pair.Key == end6)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString("d") + " " + pair.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not appropriate for sorted searches. Something like the .NET 4 `SortedDictionary` would likely be a better fit.

Comment: pagesInRange as something I forgot to delete.  The dictionary I am using is sorted by date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your intent:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a date in the following formate MM/DD/YYYY");
string date = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime startRange = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
DateTime endRange = startRange.AddDays(6);

foreach (var pair in pagesInRange)
    if (pair.Key >= startRange && pair.Key <= endRange)
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString("d") + " " + pair.Value);
```

This does not take advantage of the fact that the dictionary is sorted.

Comment: Thanks, I could not think of that one line.

Comment: @Aaron, please see revision, should have been `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ you could query like this:

```
SortedDictionary<DateTime, Page> dict = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, Page>();

...

var query = dict
    .SkipWhile(pair => pair.Key < startDate)
    .TakeWhile(pair => pair.Key <= endDate);

foreach (var pair in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using a switch statement since you have so many else if cases. The switch statement I believe can be slightly faster due to the way the compiler  uses the test conditions. Though you would have to declare end1 through n as const.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering if there is anything I do for a range of consecutive values.  Can I do something were I get my dictionary to start at this value and iterate over the next seven consecutive values

Comment: Perhaps use the switch to figure out how to increment the date and then add to the date the user inputs?